# How to post form using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with a submit button and it works fine, but I now have a user request to make the form get saved (posted to save action) if a link on the page is clicked and the form is "dirty".

I've got the logic in place by having an isDirty JavaScript variable, now I would like to post the form from the JavaScript function when it is dirty.

My form declaration is as follows:

```
    <form id="formSmart" action="<%= ResolveUrl("~/SmartForm/Proceed") %>"
          method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and my JavaScript is:

```
function checkLink() {
  if (isDirty) {
    $("#formSmart").submit();
  }
}
```

The proceed action doesn't get called, yet when I click the submit button on the form it works fine.  What am I doing wrong in the JavaScript?

**Note:** The call to checkLink() works fine, the ultimate problem is that $("#formSmart").submit(); is not posting to the Proceed action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct way of submitting the form based on what you have posted and the names match up.

Are you sure you are calling `checkLink` and is `isDirty` equal to `true`?

Put and `alert('Test');` right before you submit and in the `if` scope.

**EDIT:** To hookup your event you need to do the following:

```
$('#yourLinkID').click(checkLink(); return false;);
```

Note the `return false` which will cause your link to not execute a navigate.  If you want the link to navigate, you can just remove that part.

Comment: Yep, I've added an alert() and it is firing, no error is thrown, but my breakpoint in the controller action doesn't get hit.  When I click submit, the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: But I always want my form to navigate, just want to execute the submit (which saves the fields), but for some reason my controller post is not being called.

Comment: @Mark Kadlec can you verify that `$("#formSmart")` is not returning the correct form? Something just seems odd as everything looks like it should be working... maybe it's something so simple we are all overlooking it... fresh eyes needed possibly :)

Comment: @Kelsey, thanks for your help, is there a way to check if the JQuery is at least finding the form and trying to do a submit?

Comment: @Mark Kadlec just add the following alert: `alert($('#formSmart));`. It should display something like `[object]`. If not, then it is not finding your form.  Also check if there is something that could be intercepting the submit server side (doubtful but one more thing to check).

Comment: Well here is some strange behaviour...when I place a breakpoint (via Firebug) the submit works!  Could it be a race condition between the javascript and the link re-routing somehow?

Comment: @Mark Kadlec leave in the `return false;` which will stop the link from navigating and check if it still works. If it does then you can just leave in the return false and do the navigation manually via javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have the "return false;" in there, that would explain the behaviour, thanks again.

Comment: @Mark Kadlec if this or another answer helped you, don't forget to set the accepted answer :)

Comment: I swear I marked it, that's odd.  Should be marked now, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the requirement is that 'a link on the page is clicked'.

Perhaps attach this event to all the `<a>` tags on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // all <a> tags get the checkLink attached to them
    $("a").click(checkLink());
});
```

Comment: I'd like to call the function if a Hyperlink is clicked, so I am open to call the function in any way (either somehow on the closed event or on the onclick event).

Comment: I'm basically trying to eliminate data loss from the form and force a submit if the form is dirty

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that the browser navigate before the page performs your submit.
the solution is suspending the navigation till you save the form.

**The UGLY solution:**
you could do it buy saving the clicked url at a hidden field,
returning false to stop the navigation,
and after submit check for a value there and if it exists do navigation

**A better solution:**
post the form via ajax and after the ajax call completes(no need to check for success or error) perform the navigation(to make it really easy just use ajaxForm [ajaxForm plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/))
the only problem with this solution is if the link has target="_blank" because then you have to use window.open which might be blocked by popup blockers
[you can play with a simple jsbin sample i prepared showing this](http://jsbin.com/oletu4/9/edit)

this example post some values to an older version of this page + navigate to google, open fiddler and see that it first post and then navigate.

**If you went to the jsbin page stop reading here**
here is the Html:

```
<form id="formSmart" action="http://jsbin.com/oletu4/edit" method="post">
<input type="text" name="someLie" />
<input type="text" name="someLie2" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
<a id="lnkNavOut" href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#lnkNavOut").click(function(){
  var jqFormSmart = $("#formSmart");
  //check here if the form is dirty and needs to be saved
  var jqClickedLink = $(this);
  $.ajax({
          url: jqFormSmart.attr("action"),
          type: "POST",
          data:jqFormSmart.serialize(), 
          complete:function(){
          location = jqClickedLink.attr("href");
          }
       }); 
   return false;//stop navigation
  });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks Avi, I really appreciate the Ajax solution, looks pretty good.